# When I try to install windows 8 64-bit on a computer with windows xp 32-bit I get an error message

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit

When I try to install win8 64bit over winXp 32bit I get this error message: "Your installation media cannot be used to install windows. your current version of windows is 32-bit and does not match the architecture of the 64-bit installation media". I amd using the $69 installation disc and this computer is 64-bit cabable.

Comment: You can't do an in-place upgrade of a 32-bit OS to 64-bit.  See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8#section_3

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upgrade from a 32-bit operating system to a 64-bit operating system.

You need to boot from the disk and perform a clean install.

Comment: SLaks, I tried a clean install but to do that I had to format the drive Xp was on (using the install disk). It installed OK but then the product key would not work; I assume it was because Xp was no longer there after the format.